# Evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ by computing the Fourier series of $f(x) = x^3 - \pi^2 x$

Tags: power-series, fourier-series

I'm trying to show that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$

Evaluating $\mathbb{C}$omplex Fourier series of the following function
$$
f(x) = x^3 - \pi^2 x, \quad x \in [-\pi, \pi]
$$

I have to find the Fourier coefficients such that
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_n e^{inx}
$$

We know that
$$
c_n = \frac{1}{T} \int_{-T/2}^{T/2} f(x) e^{-inx} dx
$$

Computing $c_0$
$$
c_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (x^3 - \pi^2 x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \left[ \frac{x^4}{4} - \frac{\pi^2x^2}{2} \right]_{-\pi}^{\pi} = 0
$$

Computing $c_{n \neq 0}$,
\begin{align*}
c_{n \neq 0} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (x^3 - \pi^2 x) e^{-inx} dx 
\end{align*}

We need to compute the two following integrals
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x^3 e^{-inx} dx &= -\frac{1}{in} 2 \pi^3 (-1)^n + \frac{1}{in^3}12 \pi (-1)^n
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x e^{-inx} dx &= -\frac{1}{in} 2\pi (-1)^n
\end{align*}

Therefore, $c_{n \neq 0}$,
\begin{align*}
c_n = c_{n \neq 0} &=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (x^3 - \pi^2 x) e^{-inx} dx \\
    &= -\frac{1}{in} \pi^2 (-1)^n + \frac{1}{in^3} 6 (-1)^n + \frac{1}{in} \pi^2 (-1)^n \\
    &= \frac{6}{in^3} (-1)^n
\end{align*}

Therefore, can I write the following ?
$$
Sf(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{6}{in^3} (-1)^n e^{inx}
$$

We can then use the fact that $f(0) = Sf(0)$,
\begin{align*}
Sf(0) &= f(0) \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{6}{in^3} (-1)^n &= 0 \\
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^3} &= 0 \\
\end{align*}

But then I'm stuck...

Thanks !

Comment: The problem here is that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^3}$ is nonzero.

Comment: In your formula for $Sf(x)$ you have neglected the terms with $n<0$.

Comment: So $Sf(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left( \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} \frac{6}{in^3} (-1)^n e^{inx} + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{6}{in^3} (-1)^n e^{inx} \right)$ ? I'm confused by the fact that $f(x)$ should be equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} c_n e^{inx}$ normally with complex Fourier series, it is $f(x) = \sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty} c_n e^{inx}$

Comment: Try with $\frac{1}{12} \left(3 x^2-\pi ^2\right)$

Comment: I made a mistake, it was $c_n$, such that $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_n e^{inx}$