# Different formulation of complex Fourier series and its coefficients : $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_n e^{inx}$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series

As you know, we can write a $2\pi$ periodic function as a complex Fourier series
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_n e^{inx}, \quad f_n = e^{inx}
$$

Where $c_n$ are the complex Fourier coefficients,
$$
c_n = \langle f_n | f \rangle = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) e^{-inx} dx
$$

However, in an exam exercice, I was asked to find the Fourier coefficients such that
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_n e^{inx}
$$

FYI, the function was,
$$
f: [-\pi, \pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad f(x) = x^3 - \pi^2 x
$$

In that case, does the expression of $c_n$ changes ? If so, how do we compute the $c_n$ for the expression above ?

Comment: Not every $2\pi$-periodic function can be written as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} c_n e^{inx}$. I assume that in your exam, the function was specific to have this property.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3807362/evaluating-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2-by-computing-the-fourier-series-o That function does **not** have a Fourier series of that particular form.

Comment: The given function has non-zero Fourier coefficients for $n < 0$. Therefore, the question in your exam in non-sense.

Comment: Well well well, I made a mistake, sorry. I edited my post, it was $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_n e^{inx}$

Comment: Ok, so where are you stuck ? You just have to multiply the usual $c_n$ by $\sqrt{2 \pi}$ to get the ones appearing in the desired sum.

Comment: Yes that's what I guess in that guess. I was particularly confused by the fact that we would start from $n=1$ instead of $=-\infty$ but that was a mistake from myself.

Comment: This now looks like a duplicate of your previous question.

Comment: Yes, for sure. Should be marked as duplicated or be removed.